# Symfony Doctrine - Id length in ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I do a 'doctrine:migrations:diff', Symfony does not 'export' the field length, puts '255' instead and 'doctrine:migrations:migrate' does not work.

My two entities ORM definitions:

```
App\Resources\Domain\Stage:
type: entity
fields:
    id:
        type: stage_id
        id: true
        length: 36
    name:
        type: string
manyToOne:
    educationalAreaId:
        targetEntity: EducationalArea
        joinColumn:
            name: educationalAreaId
            referencedColumnName: id

App\Resources\Domain\EducationalArea:
type: entity
fields:
    id:
        type: educational_area_id
        id: true
        length: 36
    name:
        type: string
```

I've tried to set the 'length' property inside the manyToOne definition with no success.

(I use string type in Ids because I generate UUIDs)

Comment: I'm not familiar with yaml definition of entities, but it looks like `type`s of `id` are wrong. It should be `string`. Your values of `type`s look like column names, so you should use `column: stage_id` for this. To generate UUID you can use `generator: { strategy: UUID }`.

Comment: Take a look here for example https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product-entity

Comment: @PavelAlazankin those types are other entities. On the other hand, I didn't find any solution in the provided link. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IMO doctrine annotations are more convenient way to map your entities, but anyway I think you do something wrong with types of your fields. The `type` attribute defines the mapping type to use for the column in database, so it should be `string`, `integer`, `json_array` [etc.](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types)

According to Doctrine docs usually id field is defined separately from other fields like this:

```
App\Resources\Domain\Stage:
  type: entity
  table: products
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
manyToOne:
    educationalAreaId:
        targetEntity: EducationalArea
        joinColumn:
            name: educationalAreaId
            referencedColumnName: id
```

As it said in docs: "It has a generator tag nested inside, which specifies that the primary key generation mechanism should automatically use the database platform's native id generation strategy".

But you can find other strategies [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies).

So you can try this:

```
App\Resources\Domain\Stage:
  type: entity
  table: products
  id:
    id:
      type: string
      length: 36
      generator:
        strategy: UUID
...
```

In my case I use annotations and it works fine:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=36, options={"fixed":true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
 */
private $id;
```